# Set interval in vbscript

Tags: vbscript, wsh

I want to set interval time in vbscript
Following is my code

```
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
endTime= Timer()
'Set visibilty for the client application
objWord.Visible = True

WScript.Sleep 1000
'Close MS word process
objWord.Quit
```

I found `WScript.Sleep 1000 or WScript.Sleep(1000)` `1000 is in millisecond`
but both of them are not working fine, I am using window7

Comment: WScript.Sleep 1000 is correct. What is or is not happening?

Comment: @Remou I have no idea why but it just open the MS word but didn't close it and it is working fine with out sleep command.

Comment: Are you using it in a real .VBS file? When you use an HTA for example, it won't work because it is not run from the W/Cscript engine. In the HTA case you'd better use `window.SetTimeout("objWord.Quit", 1000)`.

Comment: Great info @AutomatedChaos :+1

Answer (score 0):

Quick-and-dirty batch command is the safest and surest (though not the most accurate) way to get a delay.

' Get a 10 seconds delay

```
Delay 10
Sub Delay( seconds )
Dim wshShell
Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
wshShell.Run "ping -n " & ( seconds + 1 ) & " 127.0.0.1", 0, True
Set wshShell = Nothing
End Sub
```

[As seen on Rob van der Woude's Scripting Page](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_time_delay.php) .Here you can also find lot of good scripts