# VB scripting set delay between commands

Tags: powershell, vbscript

Is there any way to put delay between commands e.g we have 5 command i want that run first command and wait for 3 second to run new command, Then run next command and wait for 2 second, Then run 3rd command and wait for 5 second etc etc.
I found `WScript.sleep or WScript.sleep()`

Comment: Are you asking for vbscript or powershell???

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB script + how to create delay in VB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438862/vb-script-how-to-create-delay-in-vb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**vbscript**:

```
WScript.sleep(3000) '3000 milliseconds are 3 seconds
```

**powershell**:

```
start-sleep -seconds 3
```

Comment: please read my script but it is not working. This is also my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766258/set-interval-in-vbscript#comment12433505_9766258

Comment: Run MS office successfully but not close after given time.

Comment: Tested on windows 7 pro and work great (office 2010). -can't help more of this, I'm sorry. Look better at your environnment...

Comment: which one example you are using for testing ?

Comment: convert vbs in powershell and see if error come again! If so maybe a reinstallation of office can repair comobject. In other case try reinstalling Microsoft Windows Script Host.

Comment: It is suitable for developer perspective but not suitable for client